# c# WinForm How to add button on Coordinate

Tags: c#, winforms

My idea is to add a button/custom marker to the coordinate i click on the form but i have no idea how to implement it.

```
 private void AddLogo_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    } 
private void MapBrowser_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "X-" + e.X + "Y- " + e.Y;
        var button1 = new Button { Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y) };
       
        Controls.Add(button1);

    }
```

This allow me to get a button everytime i click on the form, but my idea is to click on the form and then press the addlogo button to add a button to the form.

Comment: you will have to remember the location in the MouseUp event. Place the location in member variables of the Form

Comment: You can also store the current Location in the Form's `Tag` property, so you don't need a Field for that. -- @TekuConcept The OP is already doing that.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks! I don't know how I missed that... I'll delete my original comment.
pm100's solution should work perfectly in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a variables in the form

```
bool _placeButton = false;
int _xButton;
int _yButton;
```

then

```
private void MapBrowser_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "X-" + e.X + "Y- " + e.Y;
    _xButton = e.X;
    _yButton = e.Y;
    _placeButton = true;
}
```

and finally

```
 private void AddLogo_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(_placeButton)
    {
      _placeButton = false;
      var button1 = new Button { Location = new Point(_xButton, _yButton) };
   
      Controls.Add(button1);
   }  
    
}
```

Comment: @Chronicle - click the checkmark to say its the right answer :-)